# How do I do a callback chain with q?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, promise, q

I some problems understanding how to use "q" (https://github.com/kriskowal/q) a promises library for javascript:

```
var delayOne = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        return 'hi';
    }, 100);
};

var delayTwo = function(preValue) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        return preValue + ' my name';
    }, 200);
};

var delayThree = function(preValue) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        return preValue + ' is bodo';
    }, 300);
};

var delayFour = function(preValue) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(preValue);
    }, 400);

};

Q.fcall(delayOne).then(delayTwo).then(delayThree).then(delayFour).end();
```

this only returns undefined...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason you get "undefined" is because the functions you are chaining are not returning anything:

```
var delayOne = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    return 'hi';
  }, 100);
};
```

`delayOne` calls `setTimeout`, and returns nothing (`undefined`).

To achieve your goal you must use `Q.defer`:

```
var delayOne = function() {
  var d = Q.defer();    
  setTimeout(function() {
    d.resolve("HELLO");
  }, 100);
  return d.promise;
};

var delayTwo = function(preValue) {
   setTimeout(function() {
     alert(preValue);
   }, 
   400);
};

delayOne().then ( delayTwo );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uzJrs/2/

Comment: thank you for the solution. By side of that I have to do the decision if I use Q what would improve my code quality a lot on the other side it would result in a hard dependency. Do you got experience if this problem?

Comment: if you use many chained, async calls, then you will need some library to escape the 'Pyramid of Doom' :). I personally prefer asyncjs: https://github.com/caolan/async, and I used it with success on some medium sized projects.

Answer (score 12):

As wroniasty pointed out, you need to return a promise from each of those functions, but you should also abstract any callback oriented APIs (like `setTimeout`) as much as possible and use APIs that return promises instead.

In the case of `setTimeout`, Q already provides `Q.delay(ms)` which returns a promise that will be resolved after the specified number of milliseconds, perfect for replacing `setTimeout`:

```
var delayOne = function() {
    return Q.delay(100).then(function() {
        return 'hi';
    });
};

var delayTwo = function(preValue) {
    return Q.delay(200).then(function() {
        return preValue + ' my name';
    });
};

var delayThree = function(preValue) {
    return Q.delay(300).then(function() {
        return preValue + ' is bodo';
    });
};

var delayFour = function(preValue) {
    return Q.delay(400).then(function() {
        console.log(preValue);
    });
};

Q.fcall(delayOne).then(delayTwo).then(delayThree).then(delayFour).done();
```

(note: `end` has been replaced with `done`)